# How can Mathematica quickly evaluate a scalar $g(x,y)$ given a long list of points $(x,y)$?

Tags: evaluation

I am looking for a way that Mathematica **quickly** evaluate a scalar function $g(x,y)$ given a long list of points `{{x_1,y_1},{x_2,y_2},{x_3,y_3},{x_4,y_4},.......}`. Can this be done?

I am aware that you can do this easily for the 1-dimensional case, as shown below:

[image]

However, Mathematica does not like an input analagous to the above in 2 dimensions or higher, as shown here:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
TwoDim={{1,1},{2,3},{3,5},{4,7}};
g[{x_,y_}]:=x^2+y^2;
g/@TwoDim
```

which instantly returns

```
{2,13,34,65}
```

You can also use

```
Map[g,TwoDim]
```

and get exactly the same result

Comment: A key point of this nicely put solution is that the function call must match the input arguments to the declaration.  That is, you have to have the same format or the function doesn't match.  That is why you saw the line g[<your original input>] - it couldn't match any of the input to your function.

Answer (score 3):

The solution shown is fine but if you want to extend it to n-dimensions, try this:

```
g[a_List] := Total[#^2] & /@ a
```

Now, if you give this:

```
nDim = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
g[nDim]
(*{14, 77, 194}*)
```

It would even work for mixed dimensions within the list.